# Alias std::initializer_list in clang

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, clang++

I want to use an alias of `std::initializer_list` instead of itself like that:

```
#include<initializer_list>

template< typename T >
using InitializerList = std::initializer_list<T>;

// note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
template< typename T >
void f(InitializerList<T> list) {
}

int main() {
  // error: no matching function for call to 'f'
  f({1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
}
```

That code is fine using gcc & cl. However, using clang I get an error:

```
<source>:11:3: error: no matching function for call to 'f'
  f({1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
  ^
<source>:7:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
void f(InitializerList<T> list) {
     ^
1 error generated.
```

But an direct use of `std::initializer_list` compile with no error.

```
#include<initializer_list>

template< typename T >
void f(std::initializer_list<T> list) {
}

int main() {
  f({1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
}
```

I tried all versions of clang from **3.4.2** to **4.0.0** and got same result. Does clang's behavior meet standard?

Comment: It compiles just fine with `gcc 6.3` (http://ideone.com/pQir1C). It is a bug in clang imho.

Comment: There's a [Clang bug](https://bugs.llvm.org//show_bug.cgi?id=23689) about this.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: this is a known bug in LLVM as described by Jonas in the comments.

https://bugs.llvm.org//show_bug.cgi?id=23689